# Building CUDA object files using cmake

Tags: build, cuda, cmake

I got the following setup. I'm going to extend a framework written in C++ using MPI and other Stuff using CUDA. The Project uses cmake for building. I would like to avoid using a library for my extensions and build object files from my cuda sources. Afterwards I would like to link these object object files and some other files compiled with other compilers.
Does anyone have a clue on hwo to achieve that?

I had a look at http://code.google.com/p/cudpp/wiki/BuildingCUDPPwithCMake for getting an overview on how to use CUDA with cmake but this solution uses a library as well.

Comment: OpenCV library has gpu module accelerated with CUDA. The main approach is compile cuda file with CUDA_COMPILE CMake macro and then add object files in you ADD_EXECUTABLE or ADD_LIBRARY.. See  [OpenCV](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git)

Answer (score 28):

It is possible to compile object files with the CUDA support that comes with newer versions of cmake.  You use the `cuda_compile` command.  See below.

```
# CMakeLists.txt for G4CU project                                                                                                                                                                          
project(test-cuda-thrust-gdb)

# required cmake version                                                                                                                                                                                   
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

# packages                                                                                                                                                                                                 
find_package(CUDA)

# nvcc flags                                                                                                                                                                                               
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS};-gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20)

cuda_compile(HELPER_O helper.cu)
cuda_compile(DRIVER_O driver.cu OPTIONS -G)

cuda_add_executable(driver ${HELPER_O} ${DRIVER_O})
```

If you need more information have a look at the `FindCUDA.cmake` file.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I decided to go for the library version after all, thank you anyway

Comment: This answer is very outdated. By now (CMake 3.18 and later) `CUDA` can be used as a language in CMake like `CXX`. So there is no need for `cuda_compile` & co. Instead of `find_package(CUDA)` on uses `find_package(CUDAToolkit)` for linking against CUDA runtime and libraries. The architecture is given via `CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES`.